# How to run junit4 based concordion tests with maven?

Tags: maven, concordion

My pom.xml looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.demo.DemoTestSteps</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoTestSteps</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <propertyName>concordion.output.dir</propertyName>
                    <buildDirectory>target/concordion</buildDirectory>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
        <artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's my test class:

```
package application;

import org.concordion.integration.junit3.ConcordionTestCase;

public class Application extends ConcordionTestCase {
    public void runTest() {
    } 
}
```

So, when I run the test using `mvn clean test`, the test is executed. However, if I modify the test class a little bit, so that it uses juni4, running the previous command doesn't execute anything.

```
package application;

import org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner;

@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
public class Application {
    public void runTest() {
    } 
}

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.412 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 01 16:58:18 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/62M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362236/how-to-run-concordion-test-with-maven). They're running Concordion JUnit 4 tests successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried using your pom.xml and java classes and it works for me.

I did need to fix the missing import of RunWith in the JUnit 4 case. You might want to check why you're not getting a compile error on this?

Versions that it's working with:

- Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 21:44:56+1300)
- Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.